# querying if a gauge is x% below average

Tags: prometheus

I have a number of metrics (`node_network_*_bytes`) that I'd like to alert on if they drop more than x% below average.

I currently do something like the following for interfaces I wish to monitor:

```
rate(node_network_receive_bytes{device=~"vti-.*"}[1m]) < 6000000
```

but this obviously requires a constant value, and the interfaces all vary regarding their normal throughput. Can I instead query if the value drops more than, say, 50% below that particular gauge's average over a certain range?

I imagine this requires something like `stdvar` or `stddev` operators but I can't find any working examples, and my stats math is a little rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
  rate(node_network_receive_bytes{device=~"vti-.*"}[1m])
<
  rate(node_network_receive_bytes{device=~"vti-.*"}[1h]) * 2
```

Though this sort of alerting tends to be noisy.

Comment: Awesome, ty Mr. Brazil!

Comment: Quick follow up - when comparing two metrics using a regex that matches multiple metrics, does prometheus `map` all the comparisons or does it understand that the device matched in the first part (ie the `[1m]` line) should only be compared to the same device in the `[1h]` line?

Comment: It uses labels to match, so the devices must match here.